# Prove that the following products of prime numbers equals to infinity

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing

I can't understand how to show that the product

$\prod_{p \equiv 1(mod 3)}\frac{p}{p-1}=\infty$
and 
$\prod_{p \equiv 2(mod 3)}\frac{p}{p-1}=\infty$

I was shown a similar proof without the limitation of the modulu, but I think I didn't understand that one either, any help with how to prove this would be much appreciated.
I also have a hint, if one of the products is finite, what does it say about the Dirichle L-Series? I'm not sure where to take it.

edited: hint updated.

Comment: $\prod_{p \in S}\frac{p}{p-1}=\sum_{n \in S^*} \frac{1}{n}$, where $S^*$ is the set of natural numbers all of whose prime factors are in $S$. But I don't see immediately how it solves the modulus case. As for the hint, it says at least one of the products is $\infty$.

Comment: Then try to prove that if one of the products is infinite, then so must be the other.

Comment: would love to get some ellaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product 
$$
\prod_{p\equiv 1 (\bmod 3)}\frac{p}{p-1}=\prod_{p\equiv 1 (\bmod 3)}\left(1+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)
$$ 
converges if and only if the sum 
$$
\sum_{p\equiv 1 (\bmod 3)}\frac1{p-1}
$$
does (just take the logarithm of the infinite product to see it).
Now, the sum in question is infinite because of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.
Similar for the other residue class, ${p\equiv 2 (\bmod 3)}$.